# I can't put the timestamp from my sql database in the type="datetime-local"

Tags: php, html, datetime

I am trying to put the value of timestamp in the `datetime-local` value of the input.

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
<?php $new_datetime = date("c", strtotime($account['foo'])); ?>
<input class="numberinput" type="datetime-local" placeholder="Enter foo" value="<?php echo 
`$new_datetime ?>" name="foo" id="foo" required>`
```

In `$new_datetime` is this value: `2021-03-17T16:38:00+01:00`

this is what i tried:

```
$begindate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($account['foo']));
$begintime = date("H:i", strtotime($account['foo']));
$begintijd = $begindate." ".$begintime;
echo $begintijd; // 17-03-2021 16:38 <--- prints this
```

why does it not put it in value???

Comment: As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local you need to make the date format conform to one of the formats described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#local_date_and_time_strings . The PHP `date` function can help you with that quite easily. The date format characters you can use in PHP are described at https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php . Have you looked into any of that already? If not, why not? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: N.B. If you're outputting timezoned dates, you might want to consider whether datetime-local is actually the best type of input, or whether you want to convert the date to the user's local timezone as well before placing it into to the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input with type datetime-local need a Normalized date/time string with a letter T between Date and Time. A time zone is not permitted. The "c" format therefore does not work. The following formats can be used:

- 'Y-m-d\TH:i'
- 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
- 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v'

Example of output in the browser:

```
$inputFromMysql = "2020-06-12 14:06:44";

$normalziedForDateTimeLocal = date_create($inputFromMysql)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i');
//"2020-06-12T14:06"

echo '<input name="datetime" type="datetime-local" value="'.$normalziedForDateTimeLocal.'">';
```